# Aligning text rows on the right side in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

[image]

How would a layout like this be done in react native? I understand that I can use `justifyContent: space-between` for the first row, but how would I make the second row fill all the available space, so that **488498** of the top row is aligned on the right side with the string at the bottom row?

The only way I could think of is by using a monospace font, but that's not an alternative in this case as I'm not allowed to change the font.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `<View>` tags, one that'll have the `alignSelf: 'flex-start'` style prop (so it has variable width) and one with `justifyContent: 'space-between'` style prop (so the text fills up the empty space).

Below is an example and here's an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/HkHnV4JSN) for you to fiddle with.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            afzender:
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.paragraphRight}>
            488498
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Text>Very long text omg! This will surely be long.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  paragraphRight: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'right',
  }
});
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much, just what I needed!

Answer (score -3):

You could wrap 488498 with a div and give it  `text-align:right` OR `float:right` using CSS...

Comment: I can't use CSS with react native.

Comment: Docs say otherwise -> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text